# Restoring GRUB after Windows installation

Tags: debian, grub, lvm, luks

My Windows 7 had troubles that cloud be fix only by reinstallation. But it was not only one system in my laptop, other one was Debian Jessie. Aware about incoming GRUB overwriting I did backup of my files and installed Win 7 again.
After that I tried to restore GRUB, I encountered set of problems.

Installing Debian earlier I created LVM with three partitions inside, first for /root, second for /home and third for swap partition and encrypt all of them at the end using cryptLuks during Debian installation.
On my tries to fix it I used following commands:

1) I need to do is decrypt these partitions:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mapper/Debian-System System
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/mapper/Debian-Home Home
```

2) Next I used command **vgchange -ay**,

3) After that I mounted everything using below commands:

```
/* Debian-System is partition with system */
mount /dev/mapper/Debian-System /mnt/

/* but I cannot mount it */
mount: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'

/* so I used System, which is decrypted Debian-System */
mount /dev/mapper/System /mnt/

mount /dev/mapper/Home /mnt/home/

/* dev/sda1 is my boot partition */
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/

mount -o bind /dev/ /mnt/dev/
mount -o bind /sys/ /mnt/sys/
mount -o bind /proc/ /mnt/proc/
```

4) I **chroot**'ed to Debian (I am using x64 Ubuntu 16.04 Live DVD to fix it) and I executed commands:

```
grub-install
```

then:

```
update-grub
```

Everything looks good, but devil is in details. By using **System** instead **Debian-System** to mount and later updating GRUB, UUID in *grub.cfg* for /root partition was changed also. I edited this file and change UUID for **Debian-System** one. But I am unsure if it is enough (problably not, because few files was created during this process).

After rebooting, I saw familiar Debian boot menu again, choose Debian and later I entered password for /dev/mapper/Debian-System succefully. And good news ends here - I received following informations:

```
modprobe module luks not found in modules.dep

target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init
```

and I was drop to built-in shell (ash).

I found information that using command update-initramfs can help so I used it in next run with Ubuntu LiveDVD. I received followed text:

```
device-mapper: table ioctl on Debian-System_crypt failed: No such device or address
Command failed
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to determine cipher modules to load for Debian-System_crypt
cryptsetup: WARNING: target Debian-Swap_crypt has a random key, skipped
```

Rebooting system after that caused worse result than first one; process of asking about passphrase for Debian-System was skipped immiediately and I and I was dropped to built-in shell (ash).
Now even executing everything again (without updating initramfs) does not help - I am always repeating this same behaviour like after updating initramfs.

I am doing somdething wrong? And is there any other procedure (and chance btw.) to repair Debian and GRUB without reinstallation?
Of course I can fix it by reinstallation but I prefer to avoid it. Unless there is no other option.

Thanks for any help :)